# using screenx/screeny and their ilk, not exactly working

Tags: javascript, object, browser, model, position

my jsfiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/diabetesjones/o9o9bs0h/3/

now, this is an example coming straight out of Javascript and JQuery by Jon Duckett, but it is not working for me.

i also thought that maybe his example was wrong, and instead of

```
el.addEventListener('mousemove', showPosition, false);
```

i should put

```
el.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) { showPosition(event);});
```

but that didnt work either...been fiddling with this for a few hours now!
any clarification would be great, at this point i think its a typo. :p
thanks!!

Comment: can you use jquery ?

Comment: all fixed ill poste the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was some mistakes :

**one** : you were using : `document.getElementById('body')` and the body didnt have and `id="body"`
attribute.

**two** : you were using `sx.value`.... and you had to use `sx.innerHMTL...` becouse theya re DIV tags.

**three** : the code was excuting beofre the body was loaded thus not attahcing the event handler to it.

here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o9o9bs0h/5/) its all fixed and tested

look for your self :)

Comment: the value proprety is used with the elements thatcan hold a value like inputs and textareas select  but the innerHTML is a proprtey wich with it you can get/set the  HTML code in side the element like if you want to add an img in side a div you will do : divinnerHTML="<img ........../>"; . if you want to know the defference between innerHTML and textContent here a link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent and sorry for the delay